# Java Input Needed Twice

Tags: java

I'm having issues with an input validation code I have. I enter in my seed value it prompts me for, but afterwards I have to enter in another valid input in order to get my menu choice to print out. It happens every time I also choose one of the menu choices as well.

The input validation is supposed to take in integer values between 1 through 5 only. So if someone puts in letters, negative numbers, or integers not within the range, it asks them to put one in so that they can continue with menu choices.

Am I writing the code wrong? I want to get rid of that unnecessary second input and just only need one in order to continue with game. I also notice values after 10 works for some reason, even though 6-9 are counted as invalid. I'm not sure why that works. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sonowah
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a seed value [integer]: "); 
        //assume input is integer for seed for RNG
        int seed = in.nextInt(); 
        Random rng = new Random(seed); //RNG

        int charge = 100;

    //loop here
    while (charge > 0)
    {           
        int number;
        do 
        {
            while (!in.hasNextInt(5))
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter valid interger");
                in.next();
            }
            number = in.nextInt();
        } 
        while (number <= 0);
        System.out.println("Interger is valid!");


            System.out.println("1. Surrender");
        System.out.println("2. Defend");
        System.out.println("3. Fight");
            System.out.println("4. Charge");
            System.out.println("5. Potions");
            String menuchoice = in.next();

            if (menuchoice.equals("1"))
            {
                    statement
                }
```

Comment: Where is the rest of `main` ?

Comment: When posting code it helps to post the whole file/class so we can provide more informed answers.

Comment: The OP posted enough info. Actually, too much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your loop should be using in.hasNextInt()...you already ask the user for a number, just check if that number is between 1 and 5. Scanner.hasNextInt(5) asks the user for an int and then tries to interpret it in radix 5. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28int%29)

Comment: Hi. Thanks Tim and drew for the help! I didn't realize it was not needed. The integers are working just fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
do 
{
    while (!in.hasNextInt(5))
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter valid interger");
        in.next();
    }
    number = in.nextInt();
} 
while (number <= 0);
```

Basically, all of this code is useless in context of the rest of your program code.